# Where is this turban headpiece from?

Tags: part-identification, minifigures

[image]

Where is this turban headpiece from?

Comment: It's a LEGO minifig head with a headdress on .... Can you be more specific about what piece you need identified?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this is a non-LEGO custom turban piece:

[image: BrickForge 007-03-02]

It is manufactured by BrickForge and is available for [purchase directly from them](http://www.brickforge.com/store/product.php?productid=18522&cat=0&page=1). It's currently not available in Sand Green though, so if you're hoping to get your hands on this exact piece, you'll need to check BrickForge resellers or secondary markets such as Ebay.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a feeling it wasn't official lego, but that is okay for what I am needing it for. My dad collects nativity, and I wanted to make him a nativity for christmas, but I plan to spray paint all the pieces the same color, so actually this is awesome cuz I really hate to ruin real legos. Makes a great head piece for a shepherd.